# Just wrote code for a simple Java GUI Game. Need advise on researching and learning

Tags: java, android

as part of my college assignments I have written a Java GUI game. As a side I would like to package it up so my son can play it on his PC or Android Tablet. I just want him to have an EXE which plays but does not give him access to the source code.

I would like to begin researching how to achieve this. I am not looking for the final answer on a plate but the learning road/material I need to study to achieve this.

My weakness would be not knowing the key words to search on the web. I am thinking one might be a jar file but my experience needs much more research and learning. In laypersons terms I would class it as an EXE but again I am not sure.

Any research pointers or sites even books that you could advise would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers in advance Damo

Comment: Your question is off-topic because it's asking for book/tutorial recommendations

Comment: Okay so where do I start learning ?

Comment: There are many places to start; check out [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), people on youtube like Derek Banas, TheNewBoston or CaveOfProgramming. This site is to get help with specific programming problems. This question would be on topic if it only asked about how would you get a runnable file like exe in java, but you're asking for recommendations. Please read [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see what questions should asked on this site

Comment: Apologies if I have posted incorrectly but I do thank you for the guidance towards my learning objectives Cheer's

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is to export your project to an executable jar file. This file allows you to run the file. Make sure the manifest file states the name of the class containing the main-method in it.

Answer (score 0):

For PC, check out my [collection of links to the respective tools](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/best-jar-to-exe-conversion-tools-free-commercial.html).

For android, search for "Android application deployment" maybe?